# In a utility application, does the applicant put in arguments for usefulness, novel, and non-obvious?

Tags: patent-applications, utility-patent

I am currently reading through some utility patents on google. But I do not even see the words `useful`, `novel`, or `no-obvious` being mentioned in the patent.

In other words, who initiates the arguments for usefulness, novelty, and non-obviousness?
Where are these arguments documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No to the question in the title. The application presents and explains the invention and its features and operation.

The examiner makes a rejection on some grounds and the applicant brings forth data (for example in an affidavit from an expert) and makes arguments and possibly amendments to counter the *specific rejection* made by the examiner.

Those arguments may heavily depend on material from the specification and drawings as-filed but, current practice frowns on excessive characterization of the prior art other than to say there is a need for the present invention.

No general arguments as to why the invention is terrific and why prior art embodiments are horrible are helpful and they can be unhelpful.